Получение цены с помощью ccxt библиотеки асинхронно
import asyncio
import ccxt.async_support as ccxt
from pprint import pprint
import sys

if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())


async def ticker():

    bybit = ccxt.bybit()

    res = await bybit.fetch_ticker('BTC/USDT')
    pprint(res)

    await bybit.close()

asyncio.run(ticker())

Вот второй код который не работает и выбивают данную ошибку -
Network error: binance GET https://dapi.binance.com/dapi/v1/exchangeInfo
import asyncio
import ccxt.async_support as ccxt
from pprint import pprint
import sys
if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
async def ticker():
    binance = ccxt.binance()
    try:
        res = await binance.fetch_ticker('BTC/USDT')
        pprint(res)
    except ccxt.NetworkError as e:
        pprint(f"Network error: {e}")
    except ccxt.ExchangeError as e:
        pprint(f"Exchange error: {e}")
    except ccxt.BaseError as e:
        pprint(f"Base error: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        pprint(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        await binance.close()

asyncio.run(ticker())

Данный код работает практически со всеми биржами хорошо,но когда я использую тут binance ,он почему то прекращает свою работу.

Ну может хотя бы исключения пробовать ловить в методе ticker?

Ловил,говорит что по юрл ничего нет

Ну вот, уже что-то. Добавьте полный стек-трейс из исключения в вопрос.

Добавил в вопрос остальные данные,с отловом ошибки
